# How to check if VS is VS Enterprise via #if in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, preprocessor

I want to create a test using MS Fakes. Yet it fails in CI, so how to guard it so that it would only be compiled only in VS Enterprise env?

Comment: Microsoft Fakes are not supported in all versions of VisualStudio and are usually only included in premium versions. For example, VisualStudio2015 is only supported by the Enterprice version.

Comment: @HouSheng-MSFT: Yes, it works fine for me in VS editor, yet I want for it to be disabled when it is ran under non Enterprice environment